# Laravel include project name on line for syslog

Tags: php, laravel

I am running multiple Laravel projects on a server. They all go to syslog (which goes to splunk) however I am not able to determine which project the log line came from.

```
May 24 14:22:45 redacted laravel[20101]: production.DEBUG: this is a test from project 2 [] []
host =  redacted source =  /var/log/syslog
May 24 14:21:23 redacted laravel[19990]: production.DEBUG: this is a test from project 1 [] []
host =  redacted source =  /var/log/syslog
```

These lines were added with `php artisan tinker` - `Log::debug('this is a test...');`

Is there an easy way to include the project name or some identifier to the log line without editing every `Log::debug`, `Log::error`, etc.?

I looked on the docs and in the config file but couldn't see anything obvious.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty Simple. Extend the log class. Change the use statements to your new class wherever logging is being used. Append the `$msg` string with whatever  you need. Then call `parent::nameOfMethod($msg);`

```
class MyLog extends Log
{
    public function debug($msg)
    {
        $msg = $msg . 'project x'; //or whatever
        return parent::debug($msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: glad i could help!